# Three.js / WebGL / GLSL - What does "#include <common>" mean?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

In [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/shaders/FilmShader.js) Three.js shader example a function called `rand()` (taking a `vec2` as an argument) is used to generate random numbers.

However, the function is not defined in the shader code. Instead, it seems to get included using `#include <common>` (first line of the fragment shader).

I guess `#include` works a bit like in C/C++, but what exactly does `<common>` refer to? Is it an external file? Is it something specific to Three.js or will it also work with WebGL/GLSL in general?

Comment: I think there is shader preprocessor to add common code to the shader. But maybe i am wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is to do with how three.js tries to make shaders modular via "shaderChunks".
Examples of the included three.js shaders can be see [HERE](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib).

That particular part `#include <common>` is referring to [this "shaderChunk"](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/common.glsl.js), which seems to be included in most of the three.js shaders to provide common utility type functions and variables.

Comment: They are compiled to formatted strings and available as a dictionary in the `Three` namespace. These are then parsed in a pre processing step before yielding valid GLSL.

Comment: they are not compiled in the build process but in runtime. so you can write you can replace them with your own shader chunk